# invalid operands of types 'int' and 'const char [11]' to binary 'operator<<'

Tags: c++, char, integer, constants, operands

First of all, I'm just a beginner so I'm sorry if this would sound really stupid.

I'm currently doing a game in C++ where every move of a player corresponds to additional money and time deduction. Each player starts with 0 initial money and 30 minutes of time. I plan to have this on loop until both players have 0 time remaining.

This is part of my code:

```
if ((groupNumber1 == 1))
{
    cout<<"You now have a total of "<<"$"<< initialMoney += teensMoney <<" and have "<< initialTime -= teensTime <<" minutes remaining."<<endl;
}
else if ((groupNumber1 == 2))
{
    cout<<"You now have a total of "<<"$"<< initialMoney += familyMoney <<" and have "<<initialTime -= familyTime <<" minutes remaining."<<endl;  
}
```

Now when I run the program it gives me this:

[Error] invalid operands of types 'int' and 'const char [11]' to binary 'operator<<'

May I know where is the error?
Thank you so so much!

Comment: Looks like a precedence problem. `+=` will come AFTER `<<`. Placing some brackets should clean up the problem. But do you want to `+=` inside an output statement?

Comment: `initialMoney += teensMoney` --> `( initialMoney += teensMoney )` and `initialTime -= teensTime` --> `( initialTime -= teensTime )`. Basically, just put it in brackets.

Comment: [Documentation on C++ Operator precidence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of operator precedence rules (`<<` is evaluated before `+=` and `-=`), you need to bracket your arithmetic expressions, like this:

```
if ((groupNumber1 == 1))
{
    cout<<"You now have a total of "<<"$"<< (initialMoney += teensMoney) <<" and have "<< (initialTime -= teensTime) <<" minutes remaining."<<endl;
}
else if ((groupNumber1 == 2))
{
    cout<<"You now have a total of "<<"$"<< (initialMoney += familyMoney) <<" and have "<<(initialTime -= familyTime) <<" minutes remaining."<<endl;  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a precedence problem. += will come AFTER <<

initialMoney += teensMoney --> ( initialMoney += teensMoney )

Answer (score 1):

Echoing @user4581301's point - are you *sure* you want to use `+=` and `-=` here? That will permanently change the values stored in those variables after the printout, which I doubt is what you want to do. That would also not print out the correct values - do you see why?

Instead, just use good old fashioned `+` and `-`:

```
if (groupNumber1 == 1)
{
    cout << "You now have a total of " << "$" << initialMoney + teensMoney << " and have " << initialTime - teensTime << " minutes remaining." << endl;
}
else if (groupNumber1 == 2)
{
    cout << "You now have a total of " << "$" << initialMoney + familyMoney << " and have " << initialTime - familyTime << " minutes remaining." << endl;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplifying the problem to reduce the noise we get

```
cout << a += b << endl;
```

Due to [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), this is interpreted by the compiler as

```
(cout << a) += (b << endl);
```

and the `b << endl` stage makes no sense. You can fix this by forcing the order you want with brackets

```
cout << (a += b) << endl;
```

But I find modifying values inside output statements leads to programming mistakes because, even if you intend to update `a` with `+=`, folks expect values to come and go from an output statement unchanged. If you really want to update the value of `a`, I would remove all ambiguity with

```
a+=b;
cout << a << endl;
```

If you don't mean to update `a`

```
cout << a + b << endl;
```